# A postapocalyptic comic in the US published in the 80's?

Tags: story-identification, comics, post-apocalyptic

I can't remember the name of a Comic book series that I read in the middle to late 80's.

The books were about two young men/boys after an apocalyptic event in the US where society was broken down and it was a kind of "Wild west". A little more structure in society than what we see in the "Book of Eli" but a lot of lawlessness.

One of the boys is the son of a farmer and his parents are killed and he is on his own. 
In the first book, he meets up with a ruthless selfish streetsmart boy his own age, and they stick together.

In every one of the books they end up fighting some evil, while never setting out to be heroes. Totally western style, but a little darker. I remember 5 or 6 books ... It was not a long series.

The drawing style is not DC or Marvel, but more like the detailed dirty scenes of something like Blueberry. I don't know if it is from a European or a US company.

I have been googling for a couple weeks now, and at my local library unable to find them. Can anyone remember the name from my description?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you write reminds me of the Jeremiah comic books. It has been about 25 years ago, that I have read one of them, so my memory might play tricks on me.

[Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremiah_%28comics%29)

> Racial wars have torn the U.S. apart, resulting in a post-apocalyptic world. Many small pockets of civilization still exist; from isolated super high-tech fortresses, hidden research labs, or racial groups in walled-in cities — all fighting each other among the more regular population which in many ways resembles the "old west".
>
> Jeremiah and his friend Kurdy travel the country, taking odd jobs and getting mixed up in various affairs. Jeremiah, being the more noble of the two, often sticks his neck out to help others, while Kurdy is a more wily, opportunistic scoundrel.
>
> Despite its setting, Jeremiah's underlying motif is of hope and the survival of mankind. The storylines carry little from album to album, meaning they can be read individually.

[Author's page](http://www.hermannhuppen.com/jeremiah-analyse.shtml) (in french)

Comment: Came here to say so myself. Was turned into a TV show by JMS, ran for two seasons on Showtime (US).

Comment: Yeay ... thats the one!  Thanks.